# Facebook login status "connected" by only login on fb, but not on web app

Tags: javascript, facebook-login

in my web app I have a FB login button; when I access on FB and then go my web page, I correctly see the "Login" button and the "FB login button", because I have not given the access credentials yet. But launching a test function,on the console I see "status: connected", that tells me that I have accessed both on FB and my web app, while I am expecting "status: 'not_authorized'", because I acceded on FB but not on my web app...why?
Here's my code:

```
<script>
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') { // Logged into app and Facebook
  testAPI();
    } else if (response.status==='not_authorized'){ // Logged into FB but not into app
  alert("not_authorized");
    } else {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='Log '+'into FB'; // not logged in FB                   
    }
  }
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : '',
cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session                        
xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
version    : 'v3.2' // use version 2.2
});


FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
statusChangeCallback(response);
});

};
</script>
```

Comment: But you did login to your app before already, right? This is expected behavior - Facebook does not want to bother users all the time to explicitly login to an app _again_, if they already did so in the past. The mere fact that you are logged in to Facebook, makes the JS SDK running in your site recognize this, and therefor it automatically considers you logged in to the app.

Comment: Yes, I did login by "FB Login button" 10 days ago for the first time.

Comment: If you don’t want this to happen, then try and explicitly log out of your app. (Not sure if that will achieve the desired effect though. The _permissions_ are still granted to the app by the user, so I think it might behave the same way again on the next try after …)

Comment: If I am not mistaken you can also set for how long the authentication token is active.

Comment: So I saw that with the facebook authentication you have short lived tokens and long lived tokens. With the short lived access token the token is active for about 2 hours or so and long lived tokens are active for 90 days. here is a [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing)