# Facebook login button: already connected

Tags: javascript, facebook-login

when I try to login in my web app by FB login button, nothing happens on click, and the console show me the message:

> FB.login() called when user is already connected.

because I'm already connected into Facebook, but not on my app.
The question is: how can I hide that button and login in into my app after clicking on 'FB Login Button' ?

here's my code:

```
<script>
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

Comment: The button would have recognized the current state already (and changed itself to say log out), if you would let it - but with `data-auto-logout-link="false"`, you don’t. If you want to check on page load, whether you have a logged-in user already - then use the method the SDK provides for that.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is nott to know if I am logged on facebook or not, but to login into my app via 'FB login button', even if I am already logged on facebook. Actually I can't, because on click on it nothing happens; moreover the console says "already connected".

Comment: Well this ties into what I tried to explain to you below your other recent question on this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54862792/10955263 … This is *expected* behavior, if you do not want this, then you need to at least log out from your app first.

Comment: By using Facebook Logout Button or my app logout button?

Comment: The latter, the former would log you out of Facebook completely.

Comment: O4FS, when I come into my app, I'm still logged out; for this reason, it appears log buttons of FB and of app. The problem is that, being already logged out, I can't log in by FB button because nothing happens when I click on it(it doesn't disappear) and console shows me the message "already logged"

Comment: The button itself doesn’t do more than perform the login, _you_ need to handle what you want to happen next … that’s what the `onlogin` attribute is for, it lets you specify your JS callback that you want to execute when the user logs in using this button.